# How to put a link in a drop list option?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu

I have a drop down list. I want the options to contain 2 parts. First part will contain the name of the option and the second part will contain a link which will open a dialog box, where user can edit the name of that particular option.

When the user clicks on the name, the option should get selected. When the user clicks on edit link, it should open the dialog box, the option should not get selected in this case.

Also, I want to have access to this option's name when the user clicks on the edit link. I searched a lot on this, but could not find any solution.

Thanks.

```
var elements = ['abc', 'def', 'ghi'];
$("[name='inputboxname']").textcomplete([{
    match: /{(\w*)$/,
    search: function (term, callback) {
        callback($.map(elements, function (element) {
            return element.indexOf(term) === 0 ? element : null;
        }));
    },
    index: 1,
    replace: function (element) {
        return ['{' + element + '}', ' '];
    },
    template: function (value) {
        return '<div class="onleft">' + value + '</div><div class="onright"><a href="/edit">Edit</a> </div>';
    }
}], {
    header: '<button data-hook="addnew" class="wendda">Add new</button>',
    maxCount: 5
});
```

Comment: You should search a little harder, write some code and come back with a specific code question

Comment: You should add some code rather than asking for the entire code, a fiddle would be much appreciated

Comment: <select onChange="window.location.href=this.value">
    <option value="www.google.com">A</option>
    <option value="www.aol.com">B</option>
</select>

Comment: I am using Yuku-t jquery autocomplete. This is a jquery plugin which creates drop down list when user types in something in the input box. What I want is that user should be able to edit these options name. For that I am trying to include a edit link along with the name of the option in the template. I will update the question with the code.

Comment: using a anchor in option tag may will help you

Answer (score 0):

> I want the options to contain 2 parts. First part will contain the
>   name of the option and the second part will contain a link which will
>   open a dialog box

Basic html select tag won't help here, you need external plugin e.g. `select2`.

Answer (score 0):

Like this,

```
<select onChange="window.location.href=this.value">
    <option value="www.google.com">Google</option>
    <option value="www.gmail.com">Gmail</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer saina. But I want the select option to contain 2 parts. and It should open the dialog box, only when I click on edit link. When click on the name part of the option, it should select the option.

Answer (score 0):

You can't add `a href` tag in option, but you can use like this-

```html
<select>
    <option> option1 </option>
    <option> option1 </option>
    <option onclick="window.location.href='your_page.html'"> Option 3</option>
</select>
```

I hope it will helps you.